# Правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> А остальные, они же тоже писали, что едут?

Нужна ли запятая перед "что"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая перед "что" нужна.

[**ЧТО**, ***союз***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x)

> Выражает сообщение, высказывание, восприятие мысли, а также причину, повод, основание действия или состояния. *Сообщил, что не может приехать. Обидно, что опоздал. Такой тяжёлый, что не поднять. Почувствовал, что засыпаю.*

Вместо первой запятой лучше поставить другой знак (тире, двоеточие, вопросительный знак), так как в подобной фразе обозначается явная пауза или даже вопрос.

*А остальные — они же тоже писали, что едут?*

*А остальные? Они же тоже писали, что едут.*

Comment: В этом вопросе "же" не в тему. "Же" употребляется для подчёркивания, когда есть уверенность, а здесь ноль уверенности. Как понял, после тире идёт вопрос...

Comment: @oleedd  Мне кажется, нормально здесь всё. "Же" как раз употреблено, чтобы удостовериться, то есть спрашивающий уже точно не помнит: *Они же [вроде] тоже писали?*

Comment: "Вроде" вообще не подходит. Это "кажется". *Они, кажется, тоже писали?* Человек спрашивает, он не знает. Тогда нельзя говорить о вероятности. Понимаю, что в разговорной речи иногда лепят что попало. У меня диссонируют "же" и "тоже". Может, потому, что "же тоже" передаёт уверенность в сказанном, а здесь вопрос.

Comment: @oleedd  А мне всё подходит. Да, вопрос, который направлен на подтверждение своей инфы.

Answer (score 0):

Огромное значение на постановку знаков препинания играет контекст (которого нет).
*Александр Стрелец* дал нужную ссылку и предложил поменять первую (после "остальные") запятую на другие знаки. Согласна. Но только не на двоеточие.

Я попыталась восприять это предложение по-другому: *А остальные — что, едут?* — главная часть; *они же тоже писали* — вставная конструкция.

Тогда предложение может иметь такой вид (тире перед "что", а после — запятая). Смысл предложения становится совсем другим.
**А остальные — они же тоже писали — что, едут?

А остальные (они же тоже писали) — что, едут?**

**ЧТО** *[шт]*, чего, чему, чем, о чём и ***неизм.; местоим. сущ. и союзн. сл.***
**2. *неизм.*** В каком положении, каков, каково? *Что больной? Что наше дело?*

Comment: Никто не будет разрывать "А [объект] что" вставкой. И вообще, вставки в вопросах не в тему, потому что вопросительная интонация перебивается обычной.